# Using MYSQLI_USE_RESULT with prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

How can I use

```
$stmt = $db->query($sqlString, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
```

But with prepare function? I need it, because I am using bind params, but now I need to also use MYSQLI_USE_RESULT for big data.
I need something like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($sqlString, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);
```

Answer (score 2):

With prepared statements this is the default, from the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) (emphasis mine)...

> **Prepared statements return unbuffered result sets by default**. The
> results of the statement are not implicitly fetched and transferred
> from the server to the client for client-side buffering. The result
> set takes server resources until all results have been fetched by the
> client. Thus it is recommended to consume results timely. If a client
> fails to fetch all results or the client closes the statement before
> having fetched all data, the data has to be fetched implicitly by
> mysqli.